# 'Cannot find module' error using karma-browserify on Windows

Tags: node.js, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, browserify

I'm attempting to set up unit testing on an Angular/Browserify project using Karma, Karma-Jasmine, and Karma-Browserify. I'm on a Windows machine, for reference. `karma-cli` is on my global npm path, and `karma`, `karma-jasmine`, `karma-browserify`, and `browserify` are all local npm installs, using `-D`.

I'm trying to pull in a single spec file, which looks like:

```
var PhoneListCtrl = require('../../../public/js/app/controllers/phone-list');

describe('PhoneListCtrl', function() {
    var scope,
    ctrl;

    beforeEach(function() {
        scope = {};
        ctrl = new PhoneListCtrl(scope);
    });

    it('should create "phones" model with 3 phones', function() {
        expect(scope).not.toBe(undefined);
    });
});
```

And I get the following error every time:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'Cc/gGH'
```

I get this exact same error after cloning the following repos, installing karma and all plugins, and attempting to run their example test suites:

https://github.com/xdissent/karma-browserify
https://github.com/waye929/angular-browserify

What on earth am I doing wrong? The test spec module is found correctly, and karma seems to be finding all necessary plugins/preprocessors, but it appears that karma-browserify is tripping on the `require` statement in a spec every time, for reasons I cannot fathom.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled karma and all related plugins numerous times now, to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to find a solution. The issue was caused by `karma-browserify`'s own module name hashing function, which is incompatible with newer versions of `browserify`. There's a fork that deals with it by using `browserify`'s hashing function:

https://github.com/voidlock/karma-browserify/commit/3afe3b7485f2e4723bba5ad1c5a730d560b8c234

There's a pull request pending but in the meantime you can use the fork by placing

`"karma-browserify": "https://github.com/voidlock/karma-browserify/tarball/use-browserify-hash-function"`

in your `package.json` (dev)dependencies section.

Comment: Note - this PR was closed and this *should* no longer be an issue with the latest karma-browserify

https://github.com/xdissent/karma-browserify/pull/31